# wireless networking disabled by hardware switch. unblock only wifi?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dell, bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

when I do `sudo rkill list all`, I get :

```
0 phy0 : wireless LAN (soft and hard blocked : no)
1 brcmwl-0 : wireless LAN (soft and hard blocked : no)
2 dell-wifi : wireless LAN( both soft and hard blocked : YES)
3 dell-bluetooth : Bluetooth( both soft and hard blocked : YES)
```

Now I want to enable only dell-WiFi on, and want to keep dell-Bluetooth blocked.

I tried :

```
sudo rfkill unblock dell-wifi
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

None of the above has any effect.
I even restarted my laptop but still no effect.

EDIT : even when i tried `sudo rfkill unblock all`, but it didn't work..!

How should i do the same??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `rfkill` is like this:

`rfkill [options] command`

So, in your case you should use the following command to unblock wireless

```
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```

To unblock bluetooth you can use:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```